# Any way to FORCE "dlclose()" to free memory?

Tags: c

My application processes thousands of messages and uses dlopen / dlclose etc to call functions in shared libraries at runtime.

I have been analysing the memory at runtime and it seems (as I expected) that dlclose() does not free any malloc'ed memory after the close. So I have a rather bad memory leak....

The problem is these shared libs were written by someone else and I am not allowed to change the source. Is there any way around this? I suppose I *could* call a "subprocess" to process the message and then when it terminates the memory will dissappear for that subprocess....

Any other ideas?

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Comment: What library is this? Maybe you're supposed to free the memory returned by the function in the library yourself.

Comment: How are you measuring this?  A lot of `malloc` implementations won't actually unmap the virtual memory and return it to the OS even after it's been properly `free()`'d.

Comment: try -fno-gnu-unique linker option. at your own risk. read the manual first. You can check if that's the issue by running "readelf -Ws" against the .so file and grepping for STB_GNU_UNIQUE. This will likely destroy some sort of singleton behavior and might kill your program and render it malfunctional. Usually, it's some C++ templates or inline static stuff that's producing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether the memory "leaked" is memory allocated by the library you loaded, or by the `dlopen` implementation as part of managing the loaded libraries.

If it's allocated *by the library*, then either you are misusing the library and failing to call the right functions to instruct it to free memory it allocated, or it is poorly written and allocating (perhaps on first usage) data which it plans to keep around, reuse, and never free.

If it's allocated *by the implementation of `dlopen`*, then there's nothing wrong; this just means `dlopen` decided it can't safely unload the library, perhaps because there are still some references to its symbols hanging around. This is no problem since future loads of the same library will not consume more memory but will reuse the already-loaded copy.

Now, *assuming the problem is not that you're misusing the library*, all issues should be fixable simply by keeping the library open and not calling `dlclose`, and reusing it yourself if/when you need it next. That way, even if the library allocated memory behind your back and offers no way to free it, this will happen only **once** (the first time you load the library), not "N times", and thus it is not a "memory leak".

Comment: Hi there, I think it is a poorly written shared lib.....and thank you for your comment, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the memory allocated by the shared library which you are dlclose-ing which is staying, and you have no simple way to remove it (because you don't know which other parts of your process -e.g. which others dlopen-ed libraries is using it). If you want to understand more, read a good book on [Garbage Collection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420082795), or at least the [wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). Being a memory useful to the process is a global property of the entire process, not of particular libraries.

However, some libraries have conventions regarding memory usage, and might offer you the facility of cleaning up memory and resources. Others libraries don't release resources.
Some libraries give you the ability to give as parameters the allocation routines they are calling.

You might consider using the [Boehm conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) or chase your leaks with an utility like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Good luck, since your problem has no general solution. Perhaps telling us more about the actual libraries you are dlopen-ing might help.

And of course, there is the work-around of restarting from time to time your process.

Answer (score 1):

No, any memory allocated belongs to the process, not the library. In other words, dlclose has no way of knowing what memory was allocated by the library you're closing. Any well behaved library should provide a cleanup function, or never allocate memory that is not returned to you. Not all libraries are well behaved though...

Comment: See my answer for an easy workaround to the "not all libraries are well behaved" issue.